# Foreground property color

Tags: wpf, foreground

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="resultado" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Height="152" Margin="14,324,23,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" TextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="100" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
```

What I have to do to add Color in `Foreground` property in my C# code?

It is using this method:

```
SolidColorBrush bb = new SolidColorBrush();
```

Comment: I have reformatted your question. Also, I have updated your tags - you are asking about a particular UI toolkit (WPF) here, while the actual language of your code-behind should be relatively irrelevant. In any case (even if the fact that it is C# here were relevant), the language should be indicated in the tags rather than the question title.

Comment: There's a lot you're not telling us here. Are you using an MVVM framework or is just just binding to the code behind? If you are using a view model does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution with a ViewModel allowing you to change the TextBox color by changing he ListBox selection.

This is the .xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding color}" Text="This is a test." FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="ForegroundChooser">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Green"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Blue"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Red"/>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is the initialization and ListBox code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  VM data = new VM();

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    ForegroundChooser.SelectedIndex = 0;
    this.DataContext = data;
  }

  private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (ForegroundChooser.SelectedIndex == 0) data.color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    if (ForegroundChooser.SelectedIndex == 1) data.color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    if (ForegroundChooser.SelectedIndex == 2) data.color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  }
}
```

This is your ViewModel class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private SolidColorBrush _color;
    public SolidColorBrush color
    {
      get { return _color; }
      set
      {
        if (_color == value)
          return;
        else _color = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("color");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What you need to do is create an instance of the ViewModel class and set the .xaml `DataContext` to it.  Create a private instance of the values you want to bind to (such as `_color`), then create a public method for that value (`color` in this case) with `get` and optionally a `set` methods.  Bind to the public instance (`Foreground="{Binding color}"`).  In `set`, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("value")` to notify the bindings that the value was changed.